# save data to database using jquery calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm developing a web application using JSF as UI framework. I need to to implement organizer functionality with following features:

Retrieve a list of schedules from database. Need to iterate schedules and need to display on respective date cells in editable mode.
In other words, user should be able to click on a link in the date cell and a popup model panel will be displayed to output a list of detailed schedule information. Then the user should be able to select
the scheduls that they are interested and the application should save this information in database accordingly.

I've tried richfaces calendar component, but it could not help me accomplishing this task. I was wondering if jquery calendar is the right choice for this task. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you try jquery week calendar ...
Take check out from here 
http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk